# Angular directive testing select options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How do you select an option in an angular directive test?

```
 var options = elem.find('#test-code-select option');
 expect(angular.element(options[0]).text()).to.equal('234');
 expect(angular.element(options[1]).text()).to.equal('236');
```

These work fine, but how do I manually force the selection of an option?

```
angular.element(options[1]).click(); //nope
angular.element(options[1]).trigger('click'); //nope
angular.element(options[1]).attr('selected', true); //nope
```

EDIT:

The directive template includes a select with an internal ng-model, I suspect this is the cause of the problem:

```
<select id='test-code-select' ng-options='code as code for code in codeList' ng-model='code'>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var select = elem.find('#test-code-select');
select.val('236').change();
expect(scope.code).toEqual('236');
```

Note the call to `change()`.

Comment: surprising, but this works.  You definitely need the call to change().

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test the click handler then you just need to trigger a click event:

`angular.element(options[1]).trigger('click');`

You may have to allow the various handlers to execute by using $timeout.flush(), $scope.apply(), and/or by putting your verification code in a $timeout block.

Comment: Tried that with $timeout block, isolateScope().$apply, $digest().  Any other ideas?

Comment: Try `angular.element(options[1]).prop('selected', true);` you won't get the click handler, but you should be able to set the selected option

Comment: I assume you meant attr instead of prop.  That does alter the dom state - but I still have to process the change.

Comment: How is the click handler assigned to the element? Are you using ng-click, onClick, element.click or something else?

Comment: It's just a <select> with ng-options using ng-model. No explicit click handler. The problem seems to be that the ng-model doesn't get updated when the selected options change (in the test) - suspect this is an ng-model/binding thing.

Comment: Leaving aside that what you'd be testing there is angular's binding framework not your code, if updating the selection then digesting the scope doesn't update the model, I'm not sure what would.

Answer (score 0):

```
// UPDATE: to select multiple values pass an array
// select is selector for <select> tag, preferrably ID
select.val(['236', '479']).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this as another approach besides what has been answered by @ejain.

If you have jquery avaiable (i.e., not jqLite), I think the following should also work by triggering `change` on option:

```
var select = elem.find('#test-code-select');
var oneOption = select.find('option:contains("236")');
oneOption.prop('selected', 'selected').trigger('change');
expect(scope.code).toEqual('236');
```